# Can the Open Graph internationalize units, such as between meters and feet?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

For a social running app, if the developer were to provide a meta tag such as:

```
<meta content='16.69' property='myapp:distance'>
```

in kilometers, could the USA audience receive these in miles?

Answer (score 1):

You could try your luck with the method described here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/internationalization/ – and serve different data for different locales.

But I guess then you should provide a unit as well; I have the strong feeling otherwise it might completely mess up Facebook’s understanding of your data …